# Laravel Enlightn faced Redis throttling analayzer issue

Tags: php, laravel, redis

Laravel: 8
Enlight version:"enlightn/enlightnpro": "1.*"

When cache event view and route
php artisan route: cache
php artisan view: cache
php artisan event:cache
after that when run enlightn faced below enlightn error:

Your application uses an efficient throttling mechanism. Exception
Target class [allowed_account] does not exist.
Documentation URL: https://www.laravel-enlightn.com/docs/performance/redis-throttling-analyzer.html

To solve this enlightn error we have followed below steps:-

1. check allowed_account class define
2. allowed_account we use for the middleware key and we have properly configured this in kernel.php and also in the middleware namespace and all are correctly defined.
3. We also have to check also web.php file when we use this middleware we have correctly defined this.
4. In kernel.php we use
   'throttle' =>
   \Illuminate\Routing\Middleware\ThrottleRequestsWithRedis::class,
5. When we remove allowed_account from web.php file this error not occur
   In web.php file we define middlware as below:-
   Route::group(['middleware' => ['account', 'account_url', 'allowed_account', 'stripe_id' , 'subdomain'], 'domain' => $domain], function () {
6. We have also checked the Redis configuration it's also correct.

Please guide me on how can we solve this enlighten error is there an issue in Redis configuration or anywhere else ?